# sub rectangle region from combined area

Tags: quadratics

I have a rectangle divided like so

```
----------------------
|          |          |
|          |          | 
|          |          | W
|          |          |
|          |          |
----------------------
      L        L
```

- The total area of both regions combined is 576
- the total perimeter (including the inner fence) is 132

From this information we need to determine the sub region's perimeter....and this is where I am stuck!

We are currently working on quadratic equations at the moment, so i need to get this into the form of $ax^2+bx+c=0$

My initial thought is i need to intersect $2(L*W)=576$ and $ 3W + 4L = 132 $

$$2(L*W)=576$$
$$L*W=\frac{576}{2}$$
$$L*W=288$$

Then I take $3W + 4L = 132$ and do the following

$$3W+4L=132$$
$$4L=132-3W$$
$$L=\frac{132-3W}4$$
or
$$L=33-.75W$$

I do my substitution

$$W(33-.75W)-288=0$$

simplified (use that term loosely)

$$-.75W^2+33W-288=0$$
$$-100(-.75W^2+33W-288=0)$$
$$75W^2+3300W-28800=0$$

translating to

$$-(-3300)\pm \sqrt{(-300)^2-(4*75*28800)}\over 2*75$$

My results were $(L,W)=(9,32)$ and $(L,W)=(24,12)$

Comment: The two equations you wrote down are right. The logic is very clear, there is no reason to doubt. Something mechanical went bad later.

Comment: so am i to infer that the length of the fence could be either 12 or 36ft (since it can't really be negative feet) and then solve for the perimeter knowing that `1w*(1/2L)=(576/2)` ? Or do i blame the builders?

Comment: The equation solves nicely, positive answers, values of $W$ are $12$ and $32$. No need to worry about buying negative lengths of fence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$L = \dfrac{576}{W}$$

Substituting $L$ into $3W + 2L = 132$, yields:

$$3W^2 - 132 W + 2* 576 = 0$$

This (use the quadratic) yields two positive results for $W$:

$$W = 12~~ \text{or}~~ 32$$

Note that if we had gotten a positive and negative, we would discard the negative.

Now find the two values of $L$.

You should get $(W, L) = (12, 48)$ or $(W, L) = (32, 18)$

So, yes, this problem results in two valid and distinct results, which you should actually verify.

**Update**

We have:

$$2L = \dfrac{576}{W} \rightarrow L = \dfrac{288}{W}$$

Substituting $L$ into $3W + 4L = 132$, yields:

$$3W^2 - 132 W + 1152 = 0$$

From this we arrive at:

- $L = 9, W = 32$
- $L = 24, W = 12$

Comment: awesome, well it's good to know that i just fat fingered the math somewhere.  Also good to see how to use the proper tags for displaying equations :O

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: Hope it all helped in then end. Regards

Comment: one change i made is that it is `2(LW)=576` which changes it to `LW=288` since we know that a `4L+3W=132` and therefore `L*W` should equal half of the total area!

Comment: I will add an update later, but you might want to add an update to the actual problem, cause I want to verify all the results and make sure everything still works. Regards.

Comment: Went ahead and updated!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks! Hope you had a great day!

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: Your update is correct and I updated the answer. Regards